# Converse of Barbalat's lemma?

Tags: analysis

We have a continuously differentiable function $x(t) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\dfrac{dx}{dt} \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

> Under which assumption can we argue that $\lim_{t \to \infty} x(t)$ exists?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What form of condition? If $\frac{dx}{dt}$ approaches $0$ "quickly" then $\lim_{x\to\infty} x(t)$ exists.

Comment: Any condition for example on the second derivative (ex. bounded). As weak assumption as possible. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by quickly? Can you be more specific? Function $\sin(\ln (t))$ doesn't satisfy the above, what do you mean by quickly?

Comment: As fast or faster than $\frac{1}{t^p}$ where $p\gt 1$, for example. We cannot hope to give anything useful for situations that arise from "cancellation" of parts where the derivative is positive and parts where the derivative is negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As André Nicolas [said](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680351/converse-of-barbalats-lemma#comment1428408_680351), the natural condition is the integrability of $dx/dt$ on some interval $(a,\infty)$. This follows from a bound such as $$\left|\frac{dx}{dt}\right|\le \frac{ C}{t^p} \quad \text{ for some $p>1$} \tag{1}$$

Boundedness of second derivative is no help, because the "enemy" $x(t)=\ln t$ has $x''(t) = 1/t^2$, which is bounded on $(a,\infty)$ for any $a>0$; it even tends to zero.

But if $|x''(t)|\le C/t^p$ with $p>2$,  then integration  yields (1), hence the existence of $\lim x(t)$.